# How to write if - else and other complex operations with Java Expression Language

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, expression, el, template-engine

Greetings everyone. I would like to know if java expression language supports if-else statements. I have following java code:

```
if(request.getUser().isPremiumUser()) {

   if(!"abc123".equals(request.getUser().getPremiumId()))
     {
         System.out.println("Premium code mismatch");
     }

}
```

I would like to implement the same using expression language in an xml. I understand it is easy to do this - !"abc123".equals(request.getUser().getPremiumId() which would be user.premiumId ne 'abc123'. But how do i do if-else conditional statements in el. I googled to look for any articles but found none. Any help would be appreciated. I would it to look something like this

```
<bean id="test" class="com.experiments.TestEl">

<property id="errormessage" value="Premium Code mismatch" />
<property id="expression" value =" if  ..... else  "   />

</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must reread my question. I am not looking for if-else in java i am looking for if-else in java expression language. There is a difference  in plain java and java el. I am trying to drive the same logic i implemented in java in el.

Comment: AKAIK EL includes the ternary operator [boolean expression] ? [true value] : [false value].  If that doesn't work for you, you'll have to create a function.

Comment: @techmonster AKAIK is a typo. Antlersoft means "AFAIK" which means "As Far As I Know"

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the Java EL is to expose small/simple expression statements that map, or facilitate access, to java beans.  They are expected to be used from some scripting language (JSP, JSF, or perhaps others).  The EL supports *value expressions* and *method expressions* - but offers no direct flow control - which goes beyond the scope of simple access or control of an underlying java bean.  The flow control would/should be handled by the scripting language.

It does, as noted, offer a ternary operator, which represents a *value*.  In Java the `if ... else ...` is flow control, and does not represent a *value* - it's very much beyond the scope of Java EL.

A full list of [Java EL operators can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html).